# Arrange header params in PHP

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I am working in header authorization in plain PHP to arrange given results.

In any way i try to arrange them with

```
$headers=array(
   'Authorization:'Signature,
   'Content-Type: application/json'
);
```

but nothing seems to be working.

And the result I need to arrange is:

```
Authorization: Signature keyId="57502612d1bb2c0001000025fd53850cd9a94861507a5f7cca236882",algorithm="hmac-sha1",headers="date x-mod-nonce",signature="WBMr%2FYdhysbmiIEkdTrf2hP7SfA%3D"
```

Comment: `'Authorization:'Signature,` looks like it should be `'Authorization:Signature',`

Comment: I need to arrange all data from above, is there any special syntax for that? @kerbholz